# Get sql max datetime of multiple rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, aggregate-functions, max

This statement returns 2 rows:

```
SELECT ts.UnitId,ts.TeststepId, MAX(ts.CreatedAt)as CreatedAt 
FROM Teststep ts
INNER JOIN Unit u ON ts.UnitId = u.UnitId
Where u.TemplateId = 2 
Group by TeststepId, ts.UnitId
```

How can I get the one row with the highest `CreatedAt` date ? Should I distinct the `unitId`?

**UPDATE**

Aaron and flem aksed for more info:

```
1 Template has N Units
1 Unit has N Teststeps
```

The clustered primary key of the Teststep table is TeststepId and CreatedAt.

```
[TeststepId] [int] NOT NULL,

[Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,

[PreCondition] [nvarchar](500) NOT NULL,

[TestInstruction] [nvarchar](500) NOT NULL,

[ExpectedResult] [nvarchar](500) NOT NULL,

[CreatedAt] [datetime] NOT NULL,

[CreatedBy] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,

[UnitId] [int] NOT NULL,
```

The **Teststep** table

sample data with the most important fields in the Teststep table could be:

[image]

The teststep shows historized teststeps. From the above image you see that the TeststepId = 4 exist 2 times. A historized version (58 sec.) and a current version (59 sec.).

I want to get only the teststepid 4 with 59 seconds to show in a "current" View.

**UPDATE 2**

I want to get only the teststepid 4 with 59 seconds AND
all other teststepId`s with their current date. If there are only rows with different teststepid`s take those because they are the current rows.

I am just about to change my integration test and find about the solution.

Comment: Can you expand on what you are actually trying to achieve? e.g. What happens when there are more than units?

Comment: Agreed with @flem - do you want "the one row", or do you want one row ***PER UNITID***? Can you please specify so we know which question we're answering, and can you also specify the version of SQL Server?

Comment: @Aaron I updated my question. Your solutions both work, question is which one is faster. Usually there will not exist more than 20 teststeps with the same id but different dates. So i guess the orderby clause is faster than the CTE.

Comment: I can't tell you which one will be faster, but *you* can! Also I'm not sure I understand how they can return the same results, if there is more than one UnitId for any given TemplateId.

Comment: @Aaron sorry I should have posted from the beginning more info. The more I talk the more I see for myself where the problem lies ;-) see Update 2.

Comment: @Elisa you can't change requirements every 10 minutes and expect everyone to keep up with you. If your question has changed because you left important information out, please post a new question. [Please read this meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions).

Comment: @Aaron. Yes you are right. Funny I added more different teststeps to my integration test and my former sql works as expected lol. But your solution is right on my former origion question. I wanted the one teststep and your query got me that with the top(1) etc... I just expressed myself wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP (1) ts.UnitId, ts.TeststepId, ts.CreatedAt 
  FROM dbo.Teststep AS ts
  INNER JOIN Unit AS u 
  ON ts.UnitId = u.UnitId
  WHERE u.TemplateId = 2 
  ORDER BY ts.CreatedAt DESC;
```

If you want a row per UnitId, and SQL Server 2005+, then:

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT ts.UnitId, ts.TestStepId, ts.CreatedAt,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ts.UnitId ORDER BY ts.CreatedAt DESC)
  FROM dbo.Teststep AS ts
  INNER JOIN Unit AS u 
  ON ts.UnitId = u.UnitId
  WHERE u.TemplateId = 2 
)
SELECT UnitId, TestStepId, CreatedAt
  FROM x
  WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: The info is in the question. The OP wants the highest CreatedAt value. In the event of a tie, there is no difference.

Comment: I think we have both made assumptions. I've assumed that the OP wants the highest "createAt" for each unit. You've assumed that the OP wants the highest "createAt" for any unit.

Comment: I downvoted before realising I'd also made an assumption. Edit your post and I'll remove it.

Comment: As I stated, I didn't know I'd made an assumption. I'll be more careful next time.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative

Try this:

```
WITH Data AS
(
    SELECT ts.UnitId, ts.TeststepId, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UnitId ORDER BY ts.CreatedAt DESC) Position
        FROM Teststep ts INNER JOIN Unit u ON ts.UnitId = u.UnitId
     WHERE u.TemplateId = 2 
)
SELECT *
  FROM Data
 WHERE Position = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 x.* FROM
    (SELECT ts.UnitId,ts.TeststepId, MAX(ts.CreatedAt)as CreatedAt FROM Teststep ts 
      INNER JOIN Unit u ON ts.UnitId = u.UnitId 
      Where u.TemplateId = 2  
      Group by TeststepId, ts.UnitId
      ORDER BY ts.CreatedAt DESC) as [x]
```

Comment: @flem OP only wants the one row returned which contains the `max(ts.CreatedAt)`, which is the first row when orderd by `ts.CreatedAt` in descending order.

Comment: I think that's a little presumptuous. If that were the case, then the answer requires no grouping, just a simple `select top 1 ... where ... order by createdat desc`

Comment: See your discussion with AaronBertrand for my view on this!

Answer (score 0):

another way:

```
with cte as (
SELECT ts.UnitId,ts.TeststepId, MAX(ts.CreatedAt)as CreatedAt 
FROM Teststep ts
INNER JOIN Unit u ON ts.UnitId = u.UnitId
Where u.TemplateId = 2 
Group by TeststepId, ts.UnitId)
select ts.UnitId,ts.TeststepId, CreatedAt from cte where CreatedAt
 =(select MAX(CreatedAt) from cte)
```

Comment: You should look at the execution plan for this statement oh my... ;-)